# SASS extra bogus selectors

Tags: css, sass

We are getting bogus selectors added to the CSS. I am trying to track down if this is related to the file structure, SASS or Compass, Post CSS.

We are using string concatenation for the selectors:

```
.application-panel {

    &--left {

        .application-panel__inner {

            > .btn {
                right: 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We get this in the CSS.

```
.application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>.accordion__action, .application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>.btn, .application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>.card-action__button, .application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>.search-bar__button, .application-panel--left .calendar-registration .application-panel__inner>.link--calendar-call, .application-panel--left .calendar-registration .application-panel__inner>.link--calendar__button, .application-panel--left .copy-block__meta .application-panel__inner>.form__item--pill, .application-panel--left .form--coupon .application-panel__inner>input[type=submit], .application-panel--left .form--global-footer .application-panel__inner>input[type=submit], .application-panel--left .form .application-panel__inner>input.form__submit, .application-panel--left .links .toggle--multi-state.application-panel__inner>.toggle__trigger, .application-panel--left .pages .toggle--multi-state.application-panel__inner>.toggle__trigger, .application-panel--left .posts .toggle--multi-state.application-panel__inner>.toggle__trigger, .application-panel--left .search .toggle--multi-state.application-panel__inner>.toggle__trigger, .calendar-registration .application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>.link--calendar-call, .calendar-registration .application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>.link--calendar__button, .copy-block__meta .application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>.form__item--pill, .form--coupon .application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>input[type=submit], .form--global-footer .application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>input[type=submit], .form .application-panel--left .application-panel__inner>input.form__submit, .links .application-panel--left .toggle--multi-state.application-panel__inner>.toggle__trigger, .pages .application-panel--left .toggle--multi-state.application-panel__inner>.toggle__trigger, .posts .application-panel--left .toggle--multi-state.application-panel__inner>.toggle__trigger, .search .application-panel--left .toggle--multi-state.application-panel__inner>.toggle__trigger { right: 0;}
```

Comment: That looks crazy. How / what are you using to compile the scss to css?

Comment: What is `&--left`?